# Why isn't the code running. It isn't doing anything inside my loop. | Roblox Studio

Tags: roblox

None of it's working. Can you please help. This is in Roblox Studio.

```
    local Time = math.floor (game.Lighting:GetMinutesAfterMidnight(480/60))
    local intakeAlert = game.StarterGui.Main.IntakeAlert
    local prisonerCount = game.ReplicatedStorage.NumPrisoners
    local intake = game.ReplicatedStorage.PrisonerIntake -- This is the prisoner intake status
    
    while wait() do
        if Time == 8 then -- Checks if it is 8 hours after midnight.
            print("Prison Bus Arriving.")
            intakeAlert.Visible = true
            wait(2)
            intakeAlert.Visible = false
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code, the reason I can say that the reason it is not running is because of this line of code:

```
if Time == 8 then -- Checks if it is 8 hours after midnight.
```

The main reason is probably your time variable.

```
local Time = math.floor (game.Lighting:GetMinutesAfterMidnight(480/60))
```

First things first, [GetMinutesAfterMidnight()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Lighting/GetMinutesAfterMidnight) doesn't take any parameters. I'm not sure why there is one

Second,  you setup your variable at **runtime**, meaning its value is static. If the ingame time at runtime was 2, then the time variable would remain 2 until the script is stopped.

Here is my fix to this:

```lua
local intakeAlert = game.StarterGui.Main.IntakeAlert
local prisonerCount = game.ReplicatedStorage.NumPrisoners
local intake = game.ReplicatedStorage.PrisonerIntake -- This is the prisoner intake status

local debounce -- Make sure this event doesn't fire several times

while true do
    local currentTime = math.floor(game.Lighting.ClockTime) -- You can change this to GetMinutesBeforeMidnight if you want. Might have to do some math.

    if currentTime == 8 then -- Checks if it is 8 hours after midnight. 
        if debounce then return end -- Return if the event has already been fired.

        debounce = true
        print("Prison Bus Arriving.")
        intakeAlert.Visible = true
        wait(2)
        intakeAlert.Visible = false
    else
        debounce = false -- If its 9 after midnight, debounce will be set to false for the next day.
    end

    wait() -- You should avoid using this, I suggest changing it to something like RunService.Heartbeat:Wait() but that's your choice.
end
```